# clojure core.logic counting elements in a set

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I try to do something like this in core.logic

```
(defn count-different-elements-in-list [coll]
  (count (set coll)))
```

this works with integers just fine

```
(should= 1 (count-different-elements-in-list '(1 1 1)))
(should= 2 (count-different-elements-in-list '(1 1 2)))
(should= 3 (count-different-elements-in-list '(1 3 2)))
```

but now I'm trying to use core.logic to solve some stuff and there it get's messy

```
(run* [a b c]
  ;;the variables get values between 1 and 3
  (fd/in a b c (fd/interval 1 3))
  ;; in the list there should only be 2 different values
  (== 2 (count-different-elements-in-list '(a b c))))
```

but here comes the problem, a b c don't get passed as values to the function. They get passed as variables. With three variables count-different-elements-in-list returns always 3 and core.logic doesn't find a solution (empty list).

But I'm looking for this result.

```
([1 1 2] [1 2 1] [2 1 1] 
 [1 1 3] [1 3 1] [3 1 1]
 [2 2 1] [2 1 2] [1 2 2]
 [2 2 3] [2 3 2] [3 2 2]
 [3 3 1] [3 1 3] [1 3 3]
 [3 3 2] [3 2 3] [2 3 3])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `core.logic/project` logic vars into non-relational goals, like the normal function `count-different-elements-in-list`. Unfortunately, you cannot `project` finite domain logic vars, like `a`, `b`, and `c`, that are not constrained to a single value. (See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252104/clojure-core-logic-clpfd-projecting-fd-variables))

In the example you have, you can swap out the `fd/in` and `fd/interval` for a generated range and `membero`. This would remove the unconstrained finite domain vars, keep the range constraint for integers, and allow for projection.

```
(def interval (vec (range 1 4)))
(run* [a b c]
  (membero a interval)
  (membero b interval)
  (membero c interval)
  (project [a b c]
    (== 2 (count-different-elements-in-list (list a b c)))))
```

Comment: didn't got it, but solved the problem by applying the count-different-elements-in-list function on the result afterwards. Learning clojure takes its time.

Comment: Normal functions used in constraints, like `count-different-elements-in-list`, are considered non-relational goals in core.logic. I've reached the current edge of my knowledge, so I can't actually explain it.

Comment: Gave it another shot with an example. Does it help clear things up for you?

Comment: I wouldn't say `count-different-elements-in-list` is a non-relational goal.  It's not a goal at all.  It's just a clojure function, which is why you need to project your lvars to interact with it.